# Is it possible to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 using ROS Hydro?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,
I'm currently working on my PC with Ubuntu 12.04, working with ROS Hydro for Kawada Nextage robot.
Now, with Ubuntu 12.04 outdated, I was wondering if there could be any issues in upgrade to 14.04.

I have read that it is not easy to install ROS Hydro from source code in Ubuntu 14.04, but I am not sure if this incompatibilities are going to be present if I upgrade my system, that has already ROS Hydro installed.

Has anybody done this?
Thanks for your attention.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269331/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-12.04-to-14.04-using-ros-hydro?/) by [CesarHoyosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/30733/cesarhoyosm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-08-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use Hydro in 14.04, you'll have to build it from source. Hydro depends on a lot of 12.04 systems packages that will be replaced during the upgrade to 14.04, and I expect that most or all of Hydro will be uninstalled by the package manager as part of the upgrade.

I've never tried to build Hydro in Indigo, but I expect you'll have some trouble getting it to work. Why not upgrade to ROS Indigo? I think it would be easier to upgrade your packages to Indigo than it would be to get Hydro working in 14.04. After all, Hydro has been EOL for over two years.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CesarHoyosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/30733/cesarhoyosm/) on 2017-08-23**:
Thanks for your answer. The point is that the robot has also more than two years, and it had ros hydro installed by default. I'm going to take a look on how the system would be affected by upgrading ros. Thanks again :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-23**:
@CesarHoyosM: you could look into any of the container technologies that exist nowadays. That would allow you to run whatever OS on your desktop, but keep using ROS Hydro with your robot from within the container. Docker and Singularity are two good examples of such technology.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-08-23**:
I used to be a co-maintainer of Nextage packages until recently. I agree with @Ed Venator. Upgrading to 14.04 should be less troublesome. If you run into Nextage specific issues, feel free to create a ticket [at its repo](https://github.com/tork-a/rtmros_nextage/issues/).

**Comment by [CesarHoyosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/30733/cesarhoyosm/) on 2017-08-23**:
Thanks both, I am going to upgrade both ubuntu and ros distribution. Thanks for your answers.

**Comment by [CesarHoyosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/30733/cesarhoyosm/) on 2017-08-25**:
Well, I finnally achieve this upgrading. Two main difficulties:

1. Before upgrading ubuntu with the `update-manager`, you must remove ros-hydro, because it causes incompatibilities.
2. After upgrading, install of ROS-Indigo is just follow the wiki and check enviorements variables

Thanks! :)